# Can I open any Swift application in Silver, make changes, and then recompile for Android?

Tags: swift, remobjects

Scenario is as follows.

We have an option to purchase source code for a Swift-based application, make changes to it and then recompile for Android.  I have found https://www.remobjects.com/elements/silver/ which runs on Windows.

Is it possible to open the existing source in Silver and then do as described above, or would I need to use the specific tooling used by the original developer?

Comment: When you say "a Swift-based application," do you mean an application written with Silver and intended to run on Android, or do you actually mean an iOS application? The language really is not the most important part of this question. If this project is large enough that it is worth buying (rather than just rewriting from scratch), and it was written to run on iOS, it is not going to be trivial to port it to Android. It will be far more than recompiling, even if you might reuse some of the code with a tool like Silver.

Comment: @RobNapier

Hi Rob, thank you for the reply.  It is an India-based company that:

1) Has a Woocommerce plugin that is an interface to the database.  
2) They generate a mobile app for both Android and iOS - which they can modify for a further cost. 
3) The costs from them is too high due to the large quantity of modifications required.
4) They offer an option of purchasing the source code, which we can then modify.  
5) All they said is that the application is coded in Swift.  

I want to know if I can open the supplied code in Silver in order to modify, as I am Windows-based.

Comment: I would doubt this would work. I'm not sure what Silver is suggesting when they say they can target iOS directly from Windows. That's quite impressive if they can; I suspect there are limitations and caveats. It's also a bit unlikely that the Android version of this app is in Swift. That's extremely unusual. If they told you it's in Swift, I strongly suspect they mean it's "native" and that the Android version is in Kotlin or Java, not Swift. I'd want a lot more technical details from this vendor, and if they're unwilling or unable to provide it, I'd be very hesitant to work with them.

Comment: To the underlying question of "can I build and iOS Swift app entirely on Windows," search SO for many versions of that. I've never seen it done in a serious way (beyond hobby demo projects). Silver seems to hint that they can, but provide no details. I've never known anyone using Silver, however, and can't speak to how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a lot of changes to it, just to get it running on Android. The language you use is independent from the platform. You could probably reuse the business logic, but certainly not the GUI.